# Create a canvas on a label with an image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to make a small window inside another to put a turtle that can be moved with buttons, but the canvas does not appear
I don't know if it's because it has an image above or what :(
I tried to put the canvas in root too but it doesn't work either

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk


ventana=tk.Tk()


image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Sin título-1.gif.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
lab=tk.Label(image=image)
lab.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)
lab.pack()

ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

can = tk.Canvas(master = lab, width = 400, height = 200)
can.pack


c=turtle.RawTurtle(can)
c.pencolor("white")


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you have `can.pack` and not `can.pack()`? Also what is the point of calling `lab.place(...)` before `lab.pack()`?

Comment: ohhhhhh... thank you hahahah, Now it worked, I had no idea that the place should go later, thank you very much: D

Comment: Also you shouldn't use any widget (except `tk.Frame`/`tk.Tk`/`tk.Toplevel`) as a master.

Comment: So I replace the canvas with a frame? And could you tell me how I make the turtle transparent, is that it appears in white and covers the background image: /

Comment: @TheLizzard: _"Also you shouldn't use any widget (except tk.Frame/tk.Tk/tk.Toplevel) as a master"_ - that's not entirely true.  Using a `Canvas` is pretty common, and of course `Labelframe` and `PanedWindow` and the ttk counterparts. You can even use `Label` and `Button` widgets if you want. You can also use a `Text` widget, which can be used as a responsive master since it supports wrapping. There's not often a good reason to use these other widgets, but tkinter supports it.

Comment: @BryanOakley could you tell me how I make the turtle transparent, is that it appears in white and covers the background image :/

Comment: Canvas images support RGBA

Comment: You can use `bgpic()` to show the image inside turtle screen instead of using a label.

Comment: @BryanOakley Forgot about those, but anyways most new people that are starting to use `tkinter` shouldn't use `Label`s for the masters of `Canvas`es.